# IE: Vertical align table in middle

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

My page is centered horizontally and vertically, the page works in all browsers but for IE the page works only in `IE11` (Latest). In IE 10, 9 and 8 the table is vertical aligned at the top of the page. How can I make the vertical align work in IE 10,9 and 8, what do I need to change?

Html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <table width="350px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img border='0' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a5/Information_example_page2_300px.jpg' width='300' height='300' style="margin:25px 25px 50px 25px;">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <p style="margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;">Street<br>
                   0000AA City
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="contact">
                <p style="margin: 0px 0px 50px 0px;">
                   <span style="color:#DDB4A4;">T</span>&nbsp; <a href="tel:000000">000000</a><br>
                   <span style="color:#DDB4A4;">E</span>&nbsp; <a href="mailto:info@info.com">info@info.nl</a><br>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <p style="color:#999999; margin: 0px 0px 25px 0px; font-size: 16px;">Text</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
 </div>
<body>
```

Css

```
    html, body 
    {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table;
    }
    .container {
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .content {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    table {
        font-size:18px;
        font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #4D4D4D;
    }
    .contact a:link 
    {
        color: #4D4D4D;
         text-decoration: none;
    }
    .contact a:hover 
    {
        color: #1a0dab;
        text-decoration: underline; 
    }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/64ys7j6n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older IEs can't handle `display:table` for both html and body very well. Besides, it's not needed.

Solution: don't assign `display:table` to `html`, only to `body`. The `html` only needs `height:100%`.

```css
html {
    height:100%;
}
body 
{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/64ys7j6n/4/)

Comment: The table is now aligned at the top in every browser, I want the table to be vertical aligned in the middle.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I hadn't had enough coffee apparently. I had it working and then I removed the unused CSS before posting. But it wasn't really unused! So I edited the answer and rectified it. Sorry about that.